# Can I configure my Proton Mail with Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, configure

I am trying to configure my Proton Mail to the Thunderbird App in Ubuntu 23, can someone please direct me in the right way to find this information?

Comment: You need their [Proton Mail Bridge](https://proton.me/support/imap-smtp-and-pop3-setup). See [Proton Mail Bridge Thunderbird setup guide for Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://proton.me/support/protonmail-bridge-clients-windows-thunderbird)